# HashSet разве поддерживает сортировку при вставке?

Tags: java, коллекции

HashSet не поддерживает порядок вставки и сортировку, имеется такой код:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
while (set.size()<10)
       set.add((int)(Math.random()*10));
set.forEach(System.out::print);
```

на выходе получается сортированный список цифр `0123456789` То же самое происходит и с Стрингами

```
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();
        set2.add("b");
        set2.add("c");
        set2.add("a");
        set2.add("d");
        set2.add("e");
        set2.forEach(System.out::print);
```

в консоли  `abcde`

Получается что HashSet поддерживает сортировку???

Меняем HashSet на LinkedHashSet результат будет рандомным, т.е. в зависимости от того в каком порядке выдаст результат метод рендом

```
 Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        while (set.size()<10)
            set.add((int)(Math.random()*10));
        set.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
```

в консоли `9085431276`

Ставим ТриСет, который по документации поддерживает сортировку, на выходе `01235689` как и ожидалось.

```
 Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
        while (set.size()<10)
            set.add((int)(Math.random()*10));
       set.forEach(a-> System.out.print(a));
```

Вопрос: каким х. HashSet сортирует? если не должен этого делать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по всему, ваша имплементация `HashSet` выводит значения в порядке возрастания хешей. Для строк, которые вы привели, порядок хешей совпадает с порядком строк. Если взять другие строки, порядок хешей [будет другим](http://ideone.com/TISDnH):

```
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();
set2.add("bXYZZZ");
set2.add("c");
set2.add("a");
set2.add("d");
set2.add("e");
set2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

выводит

```
a
c
d
e
bXYZZZ
```

---

Кстати, то, что хеши односимвольных строк возрастают, это не случайность. Согласно [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--), хеш строки вычисляется по такой формуле:

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

Для односимвольной строки `n == 1`, имеем

```
s[0]*31^0 == s[0]
```

то есть хеш совпадает с самим символом. Большему символу соответствует больший хеш.

---

То же справедливо и для `HashSet<Integer>`: согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode--),

> a hash code value [...] equal to the primitive int value represented by this Integer object.

то есть хеш `Integer` совпадает со значением самого числа. Таким образом, и тут большему числу соответствует больший хеш.

---

Заметьте, что поведение, которое вы наблюдаете, не гарантировано. [Документация на `HashSet<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) гласит:

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

то есть

> Нет гарантии по поводу порядка итерирования множества. В частности, нет даже гарантии, что порядок не поменяется со временем.